# ASP.NET OData v3 vs Excel 2013: ignoring pagination?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, asp.net-web-api, odata

I'm trying to integrate an OData Web Api with Excel 2013 but I'm facing some troubles

Scenario:

- Large database view with ~40 millions rows (MySQL)
- Database-first EDMX on top of it (Entity Framework 6.1.0)
- EntitySetController.Get() to supply data to the clients (WebApi 2.1)
- Excel 2013 to consume OData feed

My server side code had to take into account the huge data that is behind, so I decorated my Get() with `[Queryable(PageSize=50)]`

```
public class SerieValuesController : EntitySetController<SerieValue, int>
{
    #region DB Property
    private EDMWarehouseViewsContainer _DB = null;
    public EDMWarehouseViewsContainer DB
    {
        get
        {
            if (_DB == null)
                _DB = new EDMWarehouseViewsContainer();
            return _DB;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    [Queryable(PageSize=50)]
    public override IQueryable<SerieValue> Get()
    {
        var options = this.QueryOptions;
        IQueryable results = DB.SerieValues;

        if (options.Filter != null)
        {
            results = options.Filter.ApplyTo(results, new ODataQuerySettings());
        }

        if (options.Top != null)
        {
            results = options.Top.ApplyTo(results, new ODataQuerySettings());
        }

        return results as IQueryable<SerieValue>;
    }

    protected override SerieValue GetEntityByKey(int id)
    {
        SerieValue entity = DB.SerieValues.Find(id);
        return entity;
    } 
}
```

If I try to get data in a browser, with these URLs

http://mymachine.lan/odata/SerieValues (this gets correctly the first 50 rows in the view, along with a `oData.nextLink` node)

http://mymachine.lan/odata/SerieValues?$skip=50 (this get correctly the next 50 rows)

When I try to consume this feed from Excel 2013, it starts downloading the data automatically, page by page, until the memory blows.

So I changed my `[Queryable]` decoration as this

```
[Queryable(PageSize=50, MaxSkip=5000)]
```

After checking in the browser (`$skip=4999` works, `$skip=5000` works, `$skip=5001` gives an error), I tried to download the data in excel again.

Unfortunately Excel stops at 5000 giving a Server Error and no data is displayed.

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Excel will ignore paging when achieving data from OData service. 
Since you set MaxSkip=5000, it will fail when the excel tries to get the 5001th record. So what is your expected behavior? If you wanna control the amount of return, you can combine $skip and $top in your query, and set MaxSkip and MaxTop in service to control the maximum value.

Comment: How can I combine $top and $skip in Excel? I can easily add such parameters to the URL if I'm getting data from a web browser, but Excel doesn't allow me to do this.

Comment: Are you using the data tab in excel? Please try to use the Url that can work in web browser to specify the location of OData feed in excel